# Ncurses screen blank on start

Tags: rust, ncurses

Whenever I launch the following program, I get an empty screen rather than the string "hello":

```
use ncurses as n;

fn main() {
    render::setup_ncurses();
    let win = n::newwin(30, 30, 0, 0);
    n::waddstr(win, "hello");
    n::wrefresh(win);
    // n::refresh(); <-- this doesn't work either
    n::getch();
    // n::wgetch(win); <-- doesn't work either
    n::endwin();
}
```

With the setup function:

```
pub fn setup_ncurses() {
    // Allows for wide characters
    n::setlocale(n::LcCategory::all, "");
    n::initscr();
    // Captures signal sequences and no buffer
    n::raw();
    // F keys and arrows
    n::keypad(n::stdscr(), true);
    // Doesn't echo typed keys
    n::noecho();
}
```

Is there some weird behavior with windows that I'm missing? This doesn't happen when using `stdscr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
let win = n::newwin(30, 30, 0, 0);
```

for:

```
let win = n::subwin(n::stdscr(), 30, 30, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I tried to go through the documentation for sub win and i don't quite understand why this makes a difference. Do you mind explaining?